# R nls function, error in lhs - rhs non-numeric argument to binary operator

Tags: r, nls

I am trying to use the nls (non linear least squared) function on some covid data. I think the error is in my "sigfunction", but I can't seem to figure out how to make it work.

```
covid <- read.csv("covid19.csv")
plot(covid$Algeria ~  covid$days,xlab = "Time (days)",ylab="Cases")
```

[image: plot of covid cases in Algeria against time]

I know that the line should follow this function.
s = width, m = middle, a = height
[image: the function the line should follow]

```
sigfunction <- function(a,x,m,s){a*exp(((x-m)/s)^2)}
mod <- nls(y ~ sigfunction, start=list(m=70,s=60,a=30), trace=TRUE)
```

but the nls command gives me the error:

```
Error in lhs - rhs : non-numeric argument to binary operator
2. nlsModel(formula, mf, start, wts)
1. nls(y ~ sigfunction, start = list(m = 70, s = 60, a = 30), trace = TRUE)
```

thanks to G. Grothendieck i fixed one problem in the function, but now when i run it i get this error:

```
Error in qr(.swts * gr) : dims [product 4] do not match the length of object [146]
```

i changed the last two lines to:

```
Algeria <- covid$Algeria
sigfunction <- function(a,x,m,s){a*exp(((x-m)/s)^2)}
mod <- nls(Algeria ~ sigfunction(a,x,m,s), start=list(x=75,m=70,s=60,a=30), trace=TRUE)
```

Comment: The arguments to sigfunction must be provided: y ~ sigfunction(a, x, m, s)

Comment: thank you for pointing out my oversight, but i edited my question because i ran into another problem in the nls